# __str__ in class is not returning a string

Tags: python

i'm building a simple query builder, however when trying to test it seems like `Query.import_('')` returns a class object instead of a string since i get `<'query.QueryBuilder'>` when i test the type. is there anyway to get it as a string?

```
class Query(object):
  """
  Query builder entry functions
  """
  @classmethod
  def _builder(cls):
      return QueryBuilder()

  @classmethod
  def import_(cls, source_type):
      return cls._builder().import_(source_type)


class QueryBuilder(object):
  """
  Query Builder is the main class that generates sql
  """
  def __init__(self, quote_char='"'):
      self._from = []
      self._import = None
      self._source_type = None
      self.quote_char = quote_char

  def import_(self, source_type):
      if source_type == SourceType.XML:
          raise KeyError('Importing a XML is not supported')
      self._source_type = source_type
      return self

  def __str__(self):
      return self.get_sql(quote_char='"')

  def get_sql(self):
      if not (self._import):
          return 'select 1 from dual'
      return 'select 1 from dual'
```

Comment: You have to explicitly call `str(QueryBuilder())` if you want a string; nothing in the code implies that `Query._builder()` should return a string.

Comment: Why do you expect or want a string?

Comment: And why did you expect `__str__` to be involved?

Comment: well it in the end return `get_sql` which is a string?

Comment: Well, of course, since your import_() method returns self.

Comment: `__str__` would return a string if it were called but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898829/str-in-class-is-not-returning-a-string#comment78756847_45898829) rightly observes, you're testing the type, not printing the object out. The `__str__` method is invoked either when you call the `str` function on it, or you call `print` on it.

In your case, you do neither. To view the `__str__` method's output, you'd do

```
x = QueryBuilder()
print(x)
```